# How to create new property in google analytics using c# code

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-console

We can create the properties manually in google analytics. But I want to create the new property by writing the c# code. I don't know which API I need to use. Please help me to create the property using c# code.

Answer (score 0):

[views.insert](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/insert) method will allow you to insert a new provile / view.

```
 /// Create a new view (profile). 
        /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/v3/reference/profiles/insert
        /// Generation Note: This does not always build corectly.  Google needs to standardise things I need to figuer out which ones are wrong.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="service">Authenticated Analytics service.</param>  
        /// <param name="accountId">Account ID to create the view (profile) for.</param>
        /// <param name="webPropertyId">Web property ID to create the view (profile) for.</param>
        /// <param name="body">A valid Analytics v3 body.</param>
        /// <returns>ProfileResponse</returns>
        public static Profile Insert(AnalyticsService service, string accountId, string webPropertyId, Profile body)
        {
            try
            {
                // Initial validation.
                if (service == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("service");
                if (body == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("body");
                if (accountId == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(accountId);
                if (webPropertyId == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(webPropertyId);

                // Make the request.
                return service.Profiles.Insert(body, accountId, webPropertyId).Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Request Profiles.Insert failed.", ex);
            }
        }
```

code ripped from [ProfilesSampleManagement](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Google%20Analytics%20API/v3/ProfilesSampleManagement)